# How to use .htaccess to allow page access in my iframe but not directly?

Tags: .htaccess, iframe, access-control

I have a site made with iframes. I have a page I want to show in my own iframes, but I want to deny direct access. How can I protect it that way in my `.htaccess`?

Comment: i tyed php Include its not what i need

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean.  Do you want to preview the page using an iframe, but it shouldn't be loaded in the browser, full screen?

Comment: When i <IFRAME> the protected Page its shows Forbidden how to make so protected File shows error only when user do Direct file request in address bar ?

Comment: You can check `Referer` (to be your website), but this can be fooled (as http headers may be forged by remote user)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `Referer` HTTP header to check if a request came from a link on your website (or img src / or iframe src for that matter):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !example.com
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/path/to/protected/page$
RewriteRule . - [F]
```

Where `example.com` is your domain name, and `/path/to/protected/page` is the paht you want to protect

However, note that this approach can be fooled, as HTTP headers can be constructed by remote user (treat http headers as user input - do not trust them ;) )

Comment: what if someone downloads my page?

Comment: what do you mean by "download my page" ? save html locally? in that case he will not be able to see that iframe content

Comment: and also what you mean by fooled?

Comment: I mean that the remote user may intentionally alter http headers, placing your domain name inside referer, in order to gain access to otherwise inaccessible page

Comment: just downloaded my website to check is this working but no the software winHTTrack downloaded the protected page with main source code

Comment: yes, sure. direct links to images can be avoided the same way (just alter the path to protect to match images folder and remove $ so it will be a wildcard)

Comment: i did RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://(www.)?name\.ru/ [NC]
RewriteRule (.png|.gif|.jpg|.jpeg)$ / [F,L] but wont work  HELP

Comment: How does this work with a Website which is placed in a subdomain of the same domain? (path/to/protected/page)

Comment: `RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !example.com` can have regular expression in domain name, in fact, as it is now, it will match for anything not **containing** example.com in its name (so example.com.ag would also match for example and be allowed)

Comment: @DamagerThedon `RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^$` means that only empty referer is allowed... thats the problem

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the htmob.referral symchip code. That's the only way this will work. I hope that helped.

Try this: // Click-jacking protection
header("X-Frame-Options: htmob.referral:pathexec.remoteshield +(*");