# How to make web page only allowed accessed by iframe

Tags: .htaccess, iframe

I have an application that embedding the content from another server via iframe. how to prevent the iframe content accessed directly over browser?

this is my page that embedding with iframe :
http://10.1.1.1/pustaka/**random/parameter**

and this is my iframe content server :
http://10.1.1.2/flipbook/**folder/related/to/random/parameter**

Comment: Instead of sharing your local urls, share screenshots and code instead

Answer (score 0):

[How to use .htaccess to allow page access in my iframe but not directly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11501110/how-to-use-htaccess-to-allow-page-access-in-my-iframe-but-not-directly)

Try searching around for answers =] I believe this one will help you out, though.