# Allow a page to only load in an iframe and prevent direct access

Tags: php, .htaccess, iframe

How can I allow my PHP file to only load in an iframe?

For example:

**Prevent direct access:**

```
example.com/Loader.php
```

**Allow iframe access:**

```
<iframe name="TEST" src="Example.com/Loader.php"></iframe>
```

Comment: Check the referer might be an option. Something similar: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11501110/how-to-use-htaccess-to-allow-page-access-in-my-iframe-but-not-directly?rq=1

Answer (score 1):

You can use JavaScript for that

```
if(window==window.top) {
    // not in an iframe
}
```