# How to allow my PHP file only load in an Iframe

Tags: javascript, php

I am trying to protect my content from example.php file. Therefore, I need to disallow direct access to this page as well as any iframe point to it without my permission.

I configure a php file called iframe.php loading iframe from example.com. This is how I did:

**Code for example.php:**

```
<?php
 session_start();
 if(!isset($_SESSION['iframe']) || !isset($_GET['internal']) || $_SESSION['iframe'] != $_GET['internal'])
{
    die("This page can be accessed just from within an iframe");
}
 unset($_SESSION['iframe']);
 ?>
```

**Code for iframe.php**

```
<?php
session_start();
$_SESSION['iframe'] = md5(time()."random sentence");
?>
<iframe src="example.php?internal=<?php echo $_SESSION['iframe'];?>" width="500" height="100"></iframe>
```

It works well. However, When I click on any link in iframe.php, I will be redirected to other page. After that, I click the Back button in browser and receive the message: "This page can be accessed just from within an iframe".

Could you please help me keep the page working perfectly after getting back?

Thank you for reading.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Allow a page to only load in an iframe and prevent direct access](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34197938/allow-a-page-to-only-load-in-an-iframe-and-prevent-direct-access)

Answer (score 0):

Its Simple, you can do it by Javascript.

```
if(window==window.top) {
    // not in an iframe
}
```

Comment: I have tried but it still hasn't worked. Please note that your code doesn't prevent iframe loading from other source.

Answer (score 0):

In your file with iframe code just set php cookies:

```
<?php
   setcookie("stackoverflow", 1);
?>
```

In your php files add code:

```
<?php
   if(isset($_COOKIE['stackoverflow'])){
      echo "";
   }
   else{
      die('Good Bye');
   }
?>
```

Best Regards ;)